# check for duplicates in a list

Tags: list, search, duplicates

How can I check if there are duplicates of some items in a list with theta(n) time?

It basically means that you can't check the whole list for each item.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to: a) just get rid of duplicates b) return the duplicates c) just know *if* there is/are one or more duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the elements and put them into a hash map (checking for a collision).

As insertion into the hash map is O(1) you should end up with O(n) (iterating over the list) + O(1) (inserting and checking the hash map for collision, chick is usually one operation of most implementations), and O(n) + O(1) -> O(n).